# Family of k-tuples of pairwise disjoint sets, fixed cardinality for each index, exist 2 numbers in different orders for each pair of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Let $(r_i)_{i \in [k]}$ be positive integers. For each $i \in [m]$, let $(A_{i,j})_{j \in [k]}$ be a $k$-tuple of pairwise disjoint sets such that $|A_{i,j}|=r_j, \forall j \in [k]$. Suppose that for each $i \neq i^\prime$, there exist $j_1 < j_2$ and $j_1^\prime < j_2^\prime$ such that
$$A_{i, j_1} \cap A_{i^\prime, j_2^\prime} \neq \emptyset ~\mathrm{and}~ A_{i, j_2} \cap A_{i^\prime, j_1^\prime} \neq \emptyset.$$
Prove that
$$m \leq \frac{(\sum_{i \in [k]} r_i)!}{\prod_{i \in [k]}r_i !}.$$

[Some thoughts]

The RHS intuitively represents the case when we use the same $\sum_{i \in [k]} r_i$ numbers to construct all $k$-tuples, and the inequality says that is the best possible.

WLOG, we assume that the disjoint union $\bigcup_{j \in [k]} A_{1, j}$ is $[\sum_{i \in [k]} r_i]$. We want to show that all the other $k$-tuples can be mapped to ones whose disjoint unions are also $[\sum_{i \in [k]} r_i]$ in some way such that after such transformation, the tuples are all distinct and still satisfy the conditions. Then as mentioned in the above remark, we can complete the proof.

[More thoughts]

Let us consider a reduced problem first, equivalently when all $r_i = 1$.
Let $k$ be a positive integer. For each $i \in [m]$, let $A_i$ be an ordered list of length $k$ with pairwise disjoint elements in $[n]$. If for each $i \neq i^\prime$, there exist $a, b \in [n]$ with $a \neq b$ such that $a$ appears before $b$ in $A_i$ and $a$ appears after $b$ in $A_{i^\prime}$, then $m \leq k!$.

[Self-solution]

Consider all the permutations of $[n]$ and choose $\pi$ among them uniformly at random. For each $A_i$, the probability that $A_i$ is a subsequence of $\pi$ in the sense that if $x$ appears before $y$ in $A_i$ then $\pi^{-1}(x) < \pi^{-1}(y)$, is clearly $1/k!$. Note that if $A_i$ is a subsequence of $\pi$, then no other $A_{i^\prime}$ could be, otherwise there will be no pair $(a, b)$ appearing in different orders. Therefore, we have $m$ disjoint events, each of which happens with probability $1/k!$, providing the desired inequality.

Now, it remains to restore the original setting. WLOG, we assume all numbers appearing in all these sets are in $[n]$ for some $n$. First, let us give each $k$-tuple all possible $r_i!$ orders for its corresponding $r_i$, and for each $i$, we join all $A_{i, j}$ together (with all possible $S = \prod_{j \in [k]}r_j !$ ordered instances) to be an ordered list $\mathcal{A}_{i, s}$ of length $R = \sum_{j \in [k]} r_j$, where $s \in [S]$ is associated in an order among all $S$ possible ones. Now we have $mS$ many ordered lists. It is easy to check that the condition that for each $i \neq i^\prime$, there exist $j_1 < j_2$ and $j_1^\prime < j_2^\prime$ such that $A_{i, j_1} \cap A_{i^\prime, j_2^\prime} \neq \emptyset ~\mathrm{and}~ A_{i, j_2} \cap A_{i^\prime, j_1^\prime} \neq \emptyset$ is a sufficient condition of that there exist $a, b \in [n]$ with $a \neq b$ such that $a$ appears before $b$ in $\mathcal{A}_{i, s}$ and $b$ appears after $a$ in $\mathcal{A}_{i^\prime, s^\prime}$, for all $s, s^\prime \in [S]$. And for two distinct ordered lists generated from the same original $k$-tuple, the latter condition can always be satisfied in any set that is given different orders. Therefore, we now have $mS$ many ordered lists of length $R$. By the previous result, we have $mS \leq R!$, giving us the desired inequality.